# From Maclaurin series to its function

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis, taylor-expansion

Is there anyone can help me recognising what's the original function of this Maclaurin series expansion below? Cheers!

$\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^{n+1}(n+1)\cfrac{x^{2n+1}}{(2n+2)!}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[WolframAlpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum+(-1)%5E(n%2B1)+(n%2B1)+x%5E(2n%2B1)%2F(2n%2B2)!,+n%3D0..Infinity) is your friend for that: try $f$ defined by $f(x)=\frac{-\sin x}{2}$. Or you could recognize something looking like $\sin$ and go with it:
$$\begin{align}
\sin x &= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (-1)^{n} \frac{x^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!}=-\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (-1)^{n+1} \frac{x^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!}=-\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (-1)^{n+1} (2n+2)\frac{x^{2n+1}}{(2n+2)!}\\&=-2 {\color{red} {\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (-1)^{n+1} (n+1)\frac{x^{2n+1}}{(2n+2)!}}}
\end{align}$$

Comment: Thanks so much for your prompt and correct answer! Now I wonder myself why I didn't do that before! Haha. Also thanks for pointing me out about WolframAlpha. I never used that before, but I think the time is coming for me to use it! :-) Cheers mate!

Answer (score 0):

$$\begin{align}\sin(x)&=\sum_{n\ge0}(-1)^n\frac{x^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!}\\&=\sum_{n\ge0}(-1)^n(2n+2)\frac{x^{2n+1}}{(2n+2)(2n+1)!}\\&=-2\sum_{n\ge0}(-1)^{n+1}(n+1)\frac{x^{2n+1}}{(2n+2)!}\end{align}$$

> $$\sum_{n\ge0}(-1)^{n+1}(n+1)\frac{x^{2n+1}}{(2n+2)!}=\frac{-\sin(x)}2$$

Comment: @ClementC. Yeah, thanks for the catch.  :D  Silly me.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! :-)

Comment: @AngghaNugraha You're welcome.  $\overbrace{\left(\ddot{\stackrel{\quad>}\smile}\right)}_{\begin{align}\hline\qquad\end{align}}$

Answer (score 0):

$$\cos x=\sum _{n=0}^{\infty }{\frac {(-1)^{n}}{(2n)!}}x^{2n}=\sum _{n=-1}^{\infty }{\frac {(-1)^{n+1}}{(2n+2)!}}x^{2n+2}=1+\sum _{n=0}^{\infty }{\frac {(-1)^{n+1}}{(2n+2)!}}x^{2n+2}$$

differentiate it
$$-\sin x=\sum _{n=0}^{\infty }{\frac {(-1)^{n+1}}{(2n+2)!}}(2n+2)x^{2n+1}$$
divide by $2$
$$\frac{-\sin x}{2}=\sum _{n=0}^{\infty }{\frac {(-1)^{n+1}}{(2n+2)!}}(n+1)x^{2n+1}$$